# Why is Google OAuth 2.0 nonce missing

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to validate a JWT after a user completed the log-in with google prompt. Specifically, i am having an issue with the nonce not being in the JWT that google sends back to me, as expected per the linked documentation below.

Here is the front end code:

```
<google-login class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id=“********.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-auto_prompt="true" data-nonce=“<randomly generated UUID>" data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/appName/rest/auth/google/login"></div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-theme="outline" data-text="sign_in_with" data-shape="rectangular" data-logo_alignment="left" data-width="269">
        <div class="S9gUrf-YoZ4jf" style="position: relative;">
            <div></div>
            <iframe src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button?type=standard&amp;theme=outline&amp;text=sign_in_with&amp;shape=rectangular&amp;logo_alignment=left&amp;width=269&amp;client_id=******.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;iframe_id=gsi_86518_300486&amp;as=xHN4SBVSZDA7r8a2zB77gA" id="gsi_86518_300486" title="Sign in with Google Button" style="display: block; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 44px; width: 289px; border: 0px; margin: -2px -10px;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</google-login>
```

And the backend verification code

```
kotlin:
...
    val token: String? = httpServletRequest?.getParameter("g_csrf_token")
    val credential: String? = httpServletRequest?.getParameter("credential")
    val googleUser = GoogleUser().fromToken(token, credential)
java:
public GoogleUser fromToken(String token, String credential){
    GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory())
        .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(<my google client id>))
        .build();


    GoogleIdToken verifiedCredential = verifier.verify(credential);
    
    Payload payload = verifiedCredential.getPayload();
    NonceEntity nonceEntity = nonceService.findByNonce(payload.getNonce());
    // payload.getNonce() is null
    ...
}
```

All of the data in the payload is what i expect while testing, it gets the test google accounts name, email... However, the payload has no nonce in it. It is my understanding from google's documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#an-id-tokens-payload that the nonce should be in the JWT that google hands back to me, is this not the case?

Help with these would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

`EDIT 1:`

After some poking around in the 'network' panel of my browser, i can confirm that the nonce is sent to google like this: `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=*******.apps.googleusercontent.com&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&nonce=<my nonce is here>&as=qQuxTPotHkqyksF1xGUJqw&channel_id=11052d41e8597dee7bdca69dee44b56619c612eb4d5618f01defe7458cd6b17f&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000` GET request status 302 (redirect)

and like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?faa=1&rip=1&continue=https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id%*****.apps.googleusercontent.com%26ux_mode%3Dpopup%26ui_mode%3Dcard%26nonce%<my nonce here>%26as%3DqQuxTPotHkqyksF1xGUJqw%26channel_id%3D11052d41e8597dee7bdca69dee44b56619c612eb4d5618f01defe7458cd6b17f%26origin%3Dhttp://localhost:9000` GET request Status 200

It appears to be in every http request made, but not in the response JWT(credential) after successful login.

`EDIT: 2` Resolution:
Using the code provided by @bdid, i was able to conclude that angular was inserting the data-nonce value via an ajax call, ie, the google script that looks for g_id_onload was examining the div before the nonce was there due to the delay in the ajax call.

Solution: We rewrote the .js such that the google scripts are only added to the page after the ajax call completes. That way, the nonce value is populated.

Alternatively, we could have moved the nonce population to the controller and resolved it server-side but this was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonce should be returned, and is in my testing. It might be worth dumping the credential to console and pasting it into an online tool like jwt.io to quickly decode to confirm if the JWT contains the nonce as expected, or if the Kotlin back-end code is mishandling nonce.

Something like this will help to quickly confirm behavior:

```
<html><body>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script>
        function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
                console.log('JWT ID token, decode me: ' + response.credential);
        };
</script>

<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
     data-nonce="foobar">
</div>
</body></html>
```

Then decoding `response.credential` should result in  `"nonce": "foobar",` being included as a field in the payload.

Comment: thanks, i was able to use the above to diagnose and resolve my issue. See EDIT: 2